# Change scrollviewer template in listbox

Tags: wpf

I'm a newbie with WPF.
I want to change the template of scroll viewer in listbox. I found an Apple style scroll bar in this [blog](http://johnnystechnicallife.blogspot.com/2013/01/apple-style-scroll-bar-in-wpf.html)

But i dont know how to apply that scroll viewer template to listbox. Can anyone help me?
Here is the `XAML`code of Apple scroll viewer template:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarDisabledBackground" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
        <Style x:Key="VerticalScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Background="#FF868686" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Height="Auto" CornerRadius="4" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="HorizontalScrollStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="10" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="true" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Cursor="Hand"/>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarDisabledBackground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="AppleStyleVerticalScrollBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="true" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}" />
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarThumb}" Cursor="Hand"/>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="AppleStyleScrollBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{x:Null}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"   
                      CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False"   
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"   
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0"   
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"   
              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1"   
              Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0"   
              Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"   
              ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Style="{DynamicResource AppleStyleVerticalScrollBarStyle}"   
                Background="{x:Null}" Width="Auto" Margin="0"/>
                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"   
              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0"   
              Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1"   
              Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"   
              ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Style="{DynamicResource HorizontalScrollStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: thanks John Saunders.

Comment: You could just wrap the ListBox in your styled ScrollViewer

Comment: Could you explain more about your idea, sa_ddam213?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ScrollViewer`, like few other controls in WPF, have some named parts. In order to be used in correct places they need to be named properly. `ScrollViewer` styling has been explained on this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278065%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) site but basically it has 3 parts `ScrollContentPresenter`, `HorizontalScrollBar` and `VerticalScrollBar`. In turn each `ScrollBar` will have its own named parts to style. And for that go to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) site. In your case you can wrap your `ListBox` in `ScrollViewer` like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ListBox/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In this case you might also consider hiding original scroll bars of your `ListBox`. If you don't put any restriction on `Height` of `Listbox` it will grow to fit all elements and this in turn will cause your `ScrollViewer` to show your custom scroll bars.
Or you can change template of your `ListBox` like this for example ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)):

```
<Style TargetType={x:Type ListBox}>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">  
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">  
               <ItemsPresenter/> 
            </ScrollViewer> 
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then customize your `ScrollViewer` there