# How to set template for listbox in WPF(Windows 10 Weather)

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, listbox, listboxitem

I am trying to create a `Windows 10` weather application in `WPF` using `C#`. I need to have a *`Listbox`* to display recent 10 day weather section. I must set template for *`Listbox`* items. I tried this:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DailyWeatherListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!--...-->
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

[This is the recent 10 day weather section (Windows 10 Weather)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kNKy.png)

Look the Windows 10 Weather. I put this image for disuse Windows 10.
I also don't know how to set `Scrollbar` in the `Listbox` corners. I would be very thankful if you could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start off something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding WeeklyWeather}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDailyWeather, Mode=TwoWay}">

    //Use ItemTemplate to set how item looks "inside"
    //I'll leave design details for you
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}"/>
                <Image Source={Binding WheatherPicturePath}/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Temperature}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    //ItemsPanel defines container for items. It can be StackPanel, Wrapanel, Grid, etc
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        //You use this place to design how container normally looks like
                        <Border Background="White">
                            //DataTemplate defined above is placed in ContentPresenter
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                //Here we catch "IsSelected" event and re-design our template to visually reflect "selected"
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Border Background="Gray">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListBox>
```

Here are couple ideas how for those bindings.

```
public class WeatherViewModel
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string WheatherPicturePath { get; set; }
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class BindedDataContext
{
    public ObservableCollection<WeatherViewModel> WeeklyWeather { get; set; }
    public WeatherViewModel SelectedDailyWeather { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Your approaches for code-behind may differ, but they need to be in place for you to use those bindings.

For such scrollbar I would look into [Change scrollviewer template in listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683477/change-scrollviewer-template-in-listbox)

Answer (score 2):

You can set a simple ListBox template like this:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DailyWeatherListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <!--Insert XAML for One Item-->
                <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

In most real world scenarios where there is more then once piece of information per item to be displayed you would define how you want your data to be displayed through a `DataTemplate`. For example if I wanted to display both the high temperature and the low temperature and style them separately: I would first create a `DailyWeather` model in c# and create a `DataTemplate` for it, like so:

```
public class DailyWeather
{
    public int High { get; set; }
    public int Low { get; set; }
    // You Would Add All Your Other Data You Want to Display Here
}
```

In your page resources (or another resource dictionary like in App.xaml):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DailyWeather}">
         <Grid>
             <StackPanel>
                 <Label FontSize="18" Content="{Binding High}"/>
                 <Label FontSize="14" Content="{Binding Low}"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

On your `ListBox` no `ItemTemplate` is required ...

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DailyWeatherListBox"/>
```

... because once you set the source to a `List<DailyWeather>`, (or do a binding like Siim Haas's answer suggests) your program will find the `DataTemplate` we defined for a `DailyWeather` object that we included in the resources.

Comment: Note that you do not set a DataTemplate's DataType when it is explicitly used, e.g. in an ItemsControl's ItemTemplate. The DataType would simply be ignored. Setting DataType only makes sense when you want to have it auto-selected. The DataTemplate would then have to be put in a ResourceDictionary.

Comment: @Clemens I have edited the post to make what I was trying to say more clear. I normally set the DataType because Visual Studio will give you intellisense (at least for with a ListView on UWP - I assume the same for WPF) which makes things easier in the long run. I don't quite understand what you mean by 'auto-selected.'

Comment: Automatic template selection is the sole purpose of the DataType property. Put the DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary (e.g. Window.Resources), then assign a DailyWeather object to e.g. the Content property of a ContentControl. The control will now automagically choose your DataTemplate for the ContentControl's ContentTemplate. Hence you would also not have to explicitly set the ListBox's ItemTemplate. Right now your answer sounds as if it would be *necessary* to set DataType (i.e. to make the Bindings in the DataTemplate work). That is not true.

Comment: See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.2) on MS Docs: *When you set this property to the data type without specifying an x:Key, the DataTemplate gets applied automatically to data objects of that type.*

Comment: ahh that makes sense. So you could (/should) define what a 'DailyWeather' object looks like in some universal spot; then set the source of the ListBox (or another control like a ListView etc.) and it would pick up the DataTemplate by it's self. If so that makes way more sense. Thanks for mentioning that: I still have lots to learn.